# What happens to an object in a queue when I delete the object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a queue which can hold a custom class named Customer:

```
private Queue<Customer> workqueue = new Queue<Customer>();
```

A GameObject of type Customer adds itself to the queue:

```
workqueque.Enqueue(this);
```

Now the same GameObject deletes itself with:

```
Destroy(this);
```

So what happens with the entry in the queue when I try to Dequeue now? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it and what happens to the queue?

Comment: You will get a null object and if you try to do anything on it you'll get "MissingReferenceException: The object of type X has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object."

Comment: as Lexicon said: You keep the entry in the collection (any not only a Queue) but the reference will be `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to `Dequeue` something that is destroyed it will find a null reference ad throw a `MissingReferenceException`

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'XXXXX' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.

As the exception notes, a common way to handle this is by doing a null check. Using your example:

```
private Queue<Customer> workQueue = new Queue<Customer>();
private Customer newCustomer = new Customer();

workQueque.Enqueue(newCustomer);
Destroy(newCustomer);

if (newCustomer != null)
{
    workQueue.Dequeue();
}
```

This obviously gets a bit more complicated once you start queuing multiple objects, but I think you get the point.

A similar thing occurs if you assign a method to an event and then destroy the component that contained the method. If this event is now triggered, then it will try to access something that doesn't exist and throw an error.